Alternative to multiline macro function design in c++
I have a design case that I want to discuss. I have a following function definition where uppercase are macros:
errorType someFunc(params) {
    
    INTEGRITY_CHECK(params)
    SET_DATA_1(params, 0, 1, 2)
    SET_DATA_2(params, 'a', 'b', 'c') 
}

These macros are defined in a common header file which is called by other files. Each of these macros are basically function calls that conditionally return.

#define INTEGRITY_CHECK(val)   \
    if (is_empty_func(val))    \
    {                          \
        LOG_ERR("Empty Data"); \
        return errorCode_1;    \
    }
    

#define SET_DATA_1(params,                                   \
                   v1,                                       \
                   v2,                                       \
                   v2)                                       \
    if (errorType retCode = some_function_set_data_1(params, \
                                                  v1,v2,v3); \
        retCode != errorCode_success)                        \
    {                                                        \
        return errorCode_2;                                  \
    }

#define SET_DATA_2(params,                                   \
                   v1,                                       \
                   v2,                                       \
                   v2)                                       \
    if (errorType retCode = some_function_set_data_2(params, \
                                                  v1,v2,v3); \
        retCode != errorCode_success)                        \
    {                                                        \
        return errorCode_3;                                  \
    }

Params is a pointer to a struct.
Sorry for the ambiguity and vagueness.
I understand the use case for the above design is not having repetitive code. We can conditionally return from a function as macros are expanded and esentially become the function. Is there a modern C++ way / using functions for this pattern that is succinct ? Or this is the use case for macros ?
Why macros are helpful ? Let's say we replace macro with a function, it'll return a value and in the function where macros are called, we have to recheck the returned value with an if.

variadic function templates can replace a lot of macros.  This looks like a candidate but I can't say for certain without knowing what params is in someFunc(params).  I can't see how that works.

Also LOG_ERR macro can be a problem if it logs place in source code. Depending what this macro does it may or may not be solved. Also which version of C++ standard do you use?

@NathanOliver params is a pointer to a struct. Think of it like a bitfield. I didn't understand how variardic functions can help. I have rephrased it properly.

@MarekR we use C++ 17

That is a code generator written in C++ preprocessor syntax. Maybe that is what you should question here.

The most obvious replacement for a sequence of conditional returns is going to be exceptions.
This is - at least if the failure paths are really exceptional (ie, unusual) - exactly what they're designed for.
If the public interface needs to remain unchanged, it's easy enough to write a wrapper like
errorType someFunc(params) {
    try {
        return someFuncImpl(params);
    } catch (Exception const& ex) {
        return ex.errorCode;
    }
}

All the macros can then be replaced by equivalent functions that simply throw on the error path.

That's really neat. Thank you so much.
